# If Else and Brackets Showing as Text in Footer

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, if-statement, tags

What am I missing here that results in If, Else, and brackets appearing in the footer? All the script in between run as needed but for some reason the If, Else, and the brackets show up as text. This is posted in my footer.php

```js
if(user.loggedin?) {
    <script>
      window.intercomSettings = {
        app_id: 'abc123',
        custom_launcher_selector:'#intercom',
        name: "<?=wp_get_current_user()->user_firstname?>", // Full name
        email: "<?=wp_get_current_user()->user_email?>", // Email address
        created_at: "<?=strtotime(wp_get_current_user()->created_at)?>" // Signup date as a Unix timestamp
      };
    </script>
    <script>
    // We pre-filled your app ID in the widget URL: 'https://widget.intercom.io/widget/'
    (function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',w.intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments);};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args);};w.Intercom=i;var l=function(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/u9m06p0a';var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);};if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})();
    </script>
} else {
    <script>
        window.intercomSettings = {
        app_id: 'abc123',
     custom_launcher_selector:'#intercom'
};
    </script>
    <script>
    // We pre-filled your app ID in the widget URL: 'https://widget.intercom.io/widget/'
    (function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',w.intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments);};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args);};w.Intercom=i;var l=function(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/u9m06p0a';var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);};if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})();
</script>
}
```

Comment: JavaScript is not PHP, everything should be written within a single script tag, or within sequential tags, but you can't nest script tags.

Comment: I've tried to do just that and it didn't run at all. Intercom provided the snippet to placed before </body> but I needed to write an If Else so both snippets could be utilized.

Comment: Then it's probably purposed to be a template, which is handled on the server before loading to a client. Are you sure the tags should be HTML tags, not PHP tags?

Comment: Yes. If I take one of the snippets exactly how it its about from the if else, it will load properly in the footer.php. An if else needs to be written to allow loading after recognition of user or visitor. It still loads fine and executes as listed above, I just get "if(user.loggedin?){}else{}" in text at the footer.

Comment: The `if ... else` should be PHP, you need PHP tags instead of HTML tags. See Super User's answer.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response and support. I have added this code the php file and I get errors that result in a role back: Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 26 of file wp-content/footer.php. Please fix and try saving again. syntax error, unexpected ' if' (T_STRING)

Answer (score 0):

> > You can write this in following ways:

```html
<script>
<?php
    if(user.loggedin?) { ?>
      window.intercomSettings = {
        app_id: 'abc123',
        custom_launcher_selector:'#intercom',
        name: "<?=wp_get_current_user()->user_firstname?>", // Full name
        email: "<?=wp_get_current_user()->user_email?>", // Email address
        created_at: "<?=strtotime(wp_get_current_user()->created_at)?>" // Signup date as a Unix timestamp
      };
    // We pre-filled your app ID in the widget URL: 'https://widget.intercom.io/widget/u9m06p0a'
    (function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',w.intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments);};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args);};w.Intercom=i;var l=function(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/u9m06p0a';var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);};if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})();
<?php } else { ?>
        window.intercomSettings = {
   app_id: 'abc123',
   custom_launcher_selector:'#intercom'
  };
    // We pre-filled your app ID in the widget URL: 'https://widget.intercom.io/widget/u9m06p0a'
    (function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',w.intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments);};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args);};w.Intercom=i;var l=function(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://widget.intercom.io/widget/u9m06p0a';var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);};if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}}})();
<?php } ?>
</script>
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response and support. I have added this code the php file and I get errors that result in a role back: Your PHP code changes were rolled back due to an error on line 26 of file wp-content/footer.php. Please fix and try saving again.
syntax error, unexpected ' if' (T_STRING)